# NPE when trying to show a Badge in RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create and attach a badge to a `CardView` inflated from xml layout inside a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MenuItemViewHolder {
    val cardView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.menu_item_card, parent, false)
    Log.i("Adapter#onBind", cardView.toString())
    val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(cardView.context)
    badgeDrawable.isVisible = true
    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, cardView)
    return MenuItemViewHolder(cardView)
}
```

The layout file has the `CardView` element nested under a `ConstraintLayout`, and the log output is indeed showing that my `cardView` variable is the `ConstraintLayout` and not the `CardView` element:

> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{3789c11 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}

Here's the layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I get the following NPE:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.setClipChildren(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Could you include your layout xml code too?

Comment: @TayfunYILDIRIM layout file added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was due to adding the Badge to the layout view, and not the content. This fixed the NPE:

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MenuItemViewHolder {
        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.menu_item_card, parent, false)
        val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(parent.context)
        val cardView = layoutView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card_view)
        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, cardView)
        return MenuItemViewHolder(layoutView)
}
```

However, the Badge still doesn't show. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126854/badge-attached-to-cardview-doesnt-show) related.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem happens cause of trying to set badgeDrawable when layout is not inflated yet.You should migrate this codes:

```
val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(cardView.context)
badgeDrawable.isVisible = true
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, cardView)
```

to your Adapter's ViewHolder class with passing necessary context paremeters. Then you could try to set badgeDrawable inside onBindViewHolder() for every item.